# "Tote" vs. "carry" in AE

Tags: word-choice, differences, american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms

Aside from formality/informality registers, what is to "tote" that is not to "carry" to AE native speakers?

Does "tote", unlike "carry", imply a certain way to hold or support something while moving?

Comment: I think the question would be better inverted: *carry* is many more things than *tote* is. You can only literally *tote* things but you can metaphorically *carry* many different things.

Comment: @nohat Sure. The thing is I already know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tote and carry mean effectively the same thing. They differ more in connotation than overt meaning.

The word tote has a connotation of something being lightweight and not a burden to the carrier.  Hence a tote-bag - a bag for carrying around small objects.  I use a bag to tote my books back and forth to school.

Carry can mean anything from picking up an object to hauling it as freight. *e.g.* I carried my books from school.  The fighter plane carries a payload of 20 megatons of high explosive.

You would not use tote for hauling heavy items.

Comment: But why dictionary definition says it's for something *heavy or substantial?* [`to carry something, especially something heavy or awkward:`](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tote)

Answer (score 1):

As a noun, 'tote' is commonly used in American English, along with bag. This is a [tote bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tote_bag).

[image]

You may also hear the *-ing* form: 'toting', as in *She was toting around her laptop all day*. This usage implies that carrying the laptop is a small burden.
But in American English I wouldn't say something like *She totes her laptop.*

Comment: Why wouldn't you say it?  Plenty of people say that.  It's a bit folksy, but it is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Seems to be not much difference between American and British English. N-gram alert: http://goo.gl/vi4O21

Comment: Those are not the only two dialects of English. I would say that some parts of America are more apt to use tote vs. carry.  But, I cannot provide any examples.

Comment: But why dictionary definition says it's for something *heavy or substantial?* [`to carry something, especially something heavy or awkward:`](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tote)

Answer (score 0):

There's also *Tote that barge! / Lift that bale!* from the song *Ol' Man River* (the musical *Showboat*). I can't imagine anyone trying to lift or carry an entire barge, nor pull it along by human muscle, so I surmise that it means to load or unload cargo on a barge by carrying it on your back.

Comment: But people most certainly *can* pull barges, and have done so, not only on the Mississippi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barge_Haulers_on_the_Volga

Answer (score -1):

In *lingua franca* AE, "tote" is just not used as a verb, unless it is some regional dialect I have not experienced. It feels dated. The noun usage of "a tote" as shorthand for a "tote bag" is more prevalent.

Comment: He used the bag to tote his stuff around. Used as a verb all the time. Possibly more in some dialects than others.